# Using relational algebra to check a condition for all

Tags: relational-theory, relational-algebra

I encountered this question while revising for my finals exam on database theory.

> The following database contains information about car repair workshops. The following tables are used:
>
> [image]
>
> Given two workshops W1 and W2, W1 is more expensive than W2 if for every car C that is repaired by both W1 and W2, the repair price for W1 is higher than the repair price for W2 for C. Write a relational algebra query to find all workshops (W1, W2) where W1 is more expensive than W2. Exclude workshops that do not repair any common cars.

I attempted to use a join naively:

1. [image: $\rho_{(w1,car,c1)}(Repairs) \bowtie_{car} \rho{(w2,car,c2)} \rightarrow A$]
2. [image]

And then simply project out the `rname` on a join with `Workshop`. However, I realised that there would exist some Repairs where c1 < c2 and c1 > c2 are both present, and it would still indicate that W1 is more expensive than W2.

I am thinking of using the division operator, but I am not sure how to proceed.